# Error when starting jobnet in Job Arranger for Zabbix

Tags: job-scheduler

I am running the following environments:

`RHEL 6.5` with `Jobarranger server 3.0.0` and `zabbix 2.4.8` (using `MySQL server 5.6`)

`Windows Server 2012 R2` with `Jobarranger agent 3.0.0` and `zabbix agent 2.4.8`

And using `windows 7` to run `Jobarranger manager 3.0.0`

I can connect into the Jobarranger server using the manager with no problems. I can also create calenders, schedulers and jobnets.

However, when we try to run a jobnet, it will first ask whether we really want to run.
After we click "Yes", it will popup a window with "I start a jobnet, are you all right?" with no buttons to press
It will hang for a long time and do nothing, and when checking related logs no job has apparently been run.

I have also tried `Jobarranger server 2.1.0` and its respective software with no luck.

Grateful if someone could shed some light on this issue, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem.

Turns out the authors of job arranger didn't really write proper descriptions in the configuration file.

In the configuration file, they used the exact wordings as the Zabbix configuration file. At one line it said it could allow multiple servers to be defined in comma delimited form. In fact they could only parse in one server. 
Another line said it could read in Zabbix server configuration with the `Include` line, but in truth it didn't seem to be working and you had to re-define all variables in their configuration file.

Once I made sure all my configurations are explicitly specified the jobs could now run.

Comment: IMHO, it is better to avoid `Include` when using Job Arranger For Zabbix. It is best suited only with Zabbix, not JAZ. You can also refer to my site `https://mastering-jaz.github.io/` which is still in progress but hope it may help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yea I have seen your website, really well built, please keep up the good work. But I am afraid our current progress does not match the content of the website, still, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I mostly do it in my free time. Perhaps you also may like to contribute, then you are welcome :)